# Insert content of (text) file with isql into table field

Tags: firebird, firebird-4.0

With Firebird, the databases can be edited quite comfortably via isql.

Now I have a database where in one field

`VALCONTENT BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT SEGMENT SIZE 80`

contains a continuous text.

I would now like to write the content of a text file into it.

Pseudocode:

```
update foo set ValContent = <ContentFromFile "C:\MyFile.txt"> where KeyField=123
```

MySQL offers similar functionality with LOAD_FILE. How does this work with isql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird ISQL does not have an option to load blob-content from a file.